# htaccess rewrite logout url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url like this

```
http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=ab720d18d2
```

Can someone help me to rewrite like this

```
http://example.com/logout/ab720d18d2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We are here to answer question. Not to write code for you.

But because it is almost christmas:

```
RewriteRule ^logout/(.*) /wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=$1
```